# Strange overflow in ruby on rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's say I have a model Item. There are a lot of items in the datatable. Item has has_one relation with other model (Price for example). I have to create relationship with create_price method.

```
item.id #=> 95000
```

Let's start...

```
price = item.create_price price: 500
price.item_id #=> 65556 // Why? Why 65556, not 95000?
```

From project:

```
CSV.foreach('file.csv', headers: true, col_sep: ';') do |row|
  Item.transaction do
    item = Item.create! article: row[0]
    gross = item.create_gross_price price: row[1]
  end
end
```

This code producing this sql:

```
INSERT INTO `gross_prices` (`catalog_url`, `count`, `created_at`, `currency_type`, `delivery_tax`, `discount`, `item_id`, `price`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2013-04-29 20:38:49', 'руб.', NULL, NULL, 65556, 52.0, '2013-04-29 20:38:49')
```

Comment: What are the types in the `Price` table? What is `create_price` doing? Can you share the code?

Comment: item_id in Price table has INT(11) type. It's working code. create_price is a magic method of has_one relationship.

Comment: Could you show actual console output? And maybe even include models.